# Hardware capabilities for a Test with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, server

I'm preparing a  load test on Web Service SOAP. I'm following the best practices of documentation:

> For testing [how JMeter performs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#sizing_threads) on a given platform, the JavaTest sampler can be used. It does not require any network access so can give some idea as to the maximum throughput achievable.

For that I have created a Test Plan with an element `Java Request Defaults` which use the class [JavaTest](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request), and set the default configuration:

```
Name:          Value
Sleep_Time     100
Sleep_Mask     0xFF
Label          ThreadNum=${_threadNum}
ResponseCode   200
ResonseMessage OK
Status         OK
SamplerData    ${QUERY}
ResultData     The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Execute on non-GUI mode:

```
jmeter -n -t E:\jmeter\4.0\Java_Request_Defaults.jmx -l E:\jmeter\4.0\Java_Request_Defaults.jtl -e -o E:\jmeter\4.0\Java_Request_Defaults
```

Result:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using E:\jmeter\4.0\Java_Request_Defaults.jmx
Starting the test @ Wed Feb 28 11:19:51 COT 2018 (1519834791517)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Wed Feb 28 11:19:52 COT 2018 (1519834792322)
... end of run
```

> ¿How to use JavaTest Class for test hardware capabilities on server jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Request sampler is not something you should use to calculate the maximum number of threads you will be able to produce on a given machine as it depends on many factors like:

- Number of virtual users (threads) in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
- Number of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers (you will need these to test your [SOAP webservice](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html))
- Request and response size
- Number of "extra" test elements like:

  - [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)
  - [PostProcesssors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
  - [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions)

So I would recommend proceeding as follows:

1. First of all make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure you have monitoring of the baseline OS health metrics on the machine where JMeter is running (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.). You can use [JMeter PerfMon](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) plugin for this.
3. Implement your web service test plan using HTTP Request samplers
4. Start test using 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load at the same time observing CPU, RAM, Disk and Network usage. Once it reaches say 90% of maximum available capacity - stop your test and see how many users where active at this moment - this will be the maximum you can mimic for **particular this test from particular this machine**. If it's enough - good for you, if not - you will have to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

More information: [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter)